# SVN commands don't recognize URL

Tags: url, svn

I'm working at a very small startup. A previous employee set up our SVN system. The SVN system is accessed through a URL of the type:

```
http://dxxx2:1080/subversion  (works in a web browser)
```

This works fine for Tortoise. No problems there. I'm trying to write a batch file to to pull down a single trunk file into a Unit Test folder for testing. All of my attempts at accessing by using the above URL results in errors saying that the URL cannot be found. For example:

When I use the form:

```
svn checkout file:///subversion/Firmware/2-branches//02_Initializations.c
```

I receive the following:

```
C:\>checkout_target.bat
C:\>svn checkout file:///subversion/Firmware/2-branches//02_Initializations.c
svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///subversion/Firmware/2-branches/02_Initializations.c'
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///subversion/Firmware/2-branches/02_Initializations.c'
```

When I use the form:

```
svn checkout http://dxxx2:1080/subversion/Firmware/2-branches/02_Initializations.c
```

I receive the following:

```
C:\>checkout_target.bat
C:\>svn checkout http://dxxx2:1080/subversion/Firmware/2-branches//02_Initializations.c
svn: E170000: URL 'http://dxxx2:1080/subversion/Firmware/2-branches/02_Initializations.c' doesn't exist
```

How do I access our SVN through a command-line command that doesn't balk at the URL or port number?
Or how do I find the local network address of our SVN server so that I can access through a script?

Comment: Please edit the question and post the exact complete error message. Also, can you reach the repo if you type the URL in a regular web browser?

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. I reposted with the error messages. And yes it does work in my web browser.

Comment: The server probably runs in a directory so your `file://` URL would need the full path before `/subversion`.

Comment: What does `svn ls http://dxxx2:1080/` reveal? If it works, try adding one pathname component at a time and see if you can spot anything unexpected. If not, maybe add the `/subversion/` path and try again.

Comment: Thanks, triplee.
svn ls http://dxxx2:1080/   -- this fails probably doesn't know SVN

Comment: Thanks, triplee.
svn ls http://dxxx2:1080/   -- this fails probably doesn't know SVN
svn ls http://dxxx2:1080/subversion  -- works!
svn ls "http://dxxx2:1080/subversion/Firmware/GSTAT Firmware/" -- works when enclosed with quotes as one directory has a space in it.
Tried substituting the "ls" with "checkout" and it works!

Will now try these in batch file. Thanks,

Comment: So the "exact complete error message" is not such, but your interpretation of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You **must read** SVN Book
2. You **must understand** SVN Book basics
3. After 1-2 you'll never use `svn co` with file-URL, only with directory-URL

   - `svn checkout http://dxxx2:1080/subversion/Firmware/2-branches/02_Initializations.c` **will not work and must not work**
   - `svn checkout http://dxxx2:1080/subversion/Firmware/2-branches/` **will work and must work**